# Angular2 Model Driven From Not Firing ngSubmit

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Going through creating my first couple of model driven forms in Angular2.  Having an issue trying to submit the form.  It appears that ngSubmit isn't firing.  Here is the tutorial I'm following: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol.

Here is my view template:

```
<form [formGroup]="sForm" novalidate (ngSumbit)="save()">

        <div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="!sForm.controls.hoverDelay.valid">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="hoverDelay">Hover Delay (millilseconds):</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input formControlName="hoverDelay" id="hoverDelay" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <span [hidden]="sForm.controls.hoverDelay.valid" [class.help-block]="!sForm.controls.hoverDelay.valid">
                HoverDelay is required and needs to be between 500 - 2000
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="hoverAction">On Hover:</label>
            <div class="btn-group" id="hoverAction">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Modal</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Navigate</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Do Nothing</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="leftClickAction">On Left Click:</label>
            <div class="btn-group" id="leftClickAction">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Modal</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Navigate</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Do Nothing</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="rightClickAction">On Right Click:</label>
            <div class="btn-group" id="rightClickAction">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Modal</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Navigate</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Do Nothing</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="sForm.value.left">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="left" /> Left
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="sForm.value.right">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="right" /> Right
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DiagramSettings, NodeAction } from '../../../model/settings/diagram-settings';
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'settings-form',
    styleUrls: ['settings-form.css'],
    templateUrl: 'settings-form.html'
})

export class SettingsFormComponent implements OnInit {

    public sForm: FormGroup;
    public submitted: boolean;

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

        this.sForm = new FormGroup({
            hoverDelay: new FormControl('500', [<any>Validators.required, CustomValidators.range([500, 2000])]),
            left: new FormControl(true, []),
            right: new FormControl(false,[])
        });

        //this.sForm = new FormGroup({
        //    hoverDelay: new FormControl(500, [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(3)])
        //});

    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    save() {

        this.submitted = true; // set form submit to true

        // check if model is valid
        // if valid, call API to save customer
        console.log('in model save. ');
    }

}
```

Not getting any runtime errors or odd behavoirs with the view template/form other than it never enters the save function when I click the submit button.  I can probably attach a (click) event to the submit button, but my understanding of Angular2 forms is that this shouldn't be necassary.  What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just a typo. You wrote `ngSumbit` instead of `ngSubmit`.

Comment: wow... @developer033 thanks, can't believe i didn't catch that